# How to append data to a global string variable?

Tags: macros, programming

Here is a minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\let\@var\@empty

\newcommand{\append}[1]{ \xdef\@var{\@var #1} }

\append{1}
\append{2}
\append{3}

\@var

\end{document}
```

I was expecting `\@var` to contain the string `1 2 3`, but instead I get the following error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@var->\@var
```

How can I achieve what I was expecting to achieve?

Comment: All 'works for me' (if I add the `\makeatletter` required): did you run _exactly_ this file?

Comment: By the way -- you won't get `1 2 3` but `123`. If you want to have the space in between you have to use `\@var\ #1`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not “backslash-space”, but `\space`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pairs -- those are necessary due to `\@` as macro (starter) name.

If the 'string' macro should not be indicated as internal (`\@....` are internally 'hidden) choose another name, like `\mystringvar`, this will remove the issue with `\makeatletter...\makeatother`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\let\@var\@empty
\newcommand{\append}[1]{\xdef\@var{\@var #1} }
% Another variant with kernel \g@addto@macro
\newcommand{\appendother}[1]{\g@addto@macro{\@var}{#1}}

\makeatother
\newcommand{\foo}{789}

\append{1}
\append{2}
\append{3}
\appendother{456\foo}
\makeatletter
\@var
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why, using your definitions of `\append` and `\appendother`, writing `\appendother{\textbf{3}}` gives the expected result, but `\append{\textbf{3}}` throws the error `! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.`  ?

Comment: @Ceilican: `\xdef` can't be applied to a protected macro like `\textbf`

Answer (score 2):

Christian has shown what you could do instead but to explain the error

`@` is not a letter in the main document so

```
\let\@var\@empty
```

does

```
 \let\@=v
```

then typesets `ar\@empty` producing the paragraph text `arvempty` (which you don't see as later errors prevent a pdf being made.

Then

```
\newcommand{\append}[1]{ \xdef\@var{\@var #1} }
```

defines `\append` to typeset a space (why?) and then redefine `\@` then typeset another space.

```
\append{1}
```

is therefore a space (ignored as we are in vertical mode) then

```
\xdef\@var{\@var 1}
```

this is defining the macro `\@` to be followed by the tokens `var` to be the expansion of `\@var 1` now at this point `\@` is non-expandable as it is `\let` to `v` so now `\@` has to be followed by `var` and expands to `\@var 1`

Then another ignored space is output and

```
\append{2}
```

this outputs another space then

```
\xdef\@var{\@var 2}
```

which again is redefining `\@` to be a macro that must be followed by `var` but the definition is obtained by expanding `\@var 1` but as noted above the expansion of `\@var` is at this point `\@var 1` so the first expansion produces

```
\@var 1 2
```

Then `\@` expands again producing

```
\@var 1 1 2
```

and so on until you run out of input stack. (because the 1's are all being pushed ahead of you)